# view over layout and equal height columns

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I've tried a couple of things and read many topics, but I didn't find any solution for my problem.

At the moment I have an xml file with the layout on the picture. This is how it should look like the design and I did it with LinearLayouts and works perfect.

The problem is that I want when I click somewhere on the screen to add a highlighted column from top to bottom. 
I read that this should be done with RelativeLayout, but I tried to do it that way, but I can't arrange my other elements to be with equal size.

Do you know how this could be done ?

This is part of my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart1Layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/color"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="@string/cap"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.some.chart
        android:id="@+id/result_widget_chartView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        palette="grayscale"
        android:background="@color/dark_header"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Design : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkHvG.png

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

see my pic:

if this what you want?

[image: effect]

[image: code]

Comment: Hi kevinhoo, sorry but I don't get your idea. Could you be more detailed?
My idea is to add a view (column) with semi-transperent color which cover all from top to bottom  in the touched place. 
I don't know but I can't post the xml because the comment removes some text from it.
I have root Vertical Linner Layout and all other components are as in the code above - in Horizontal Linner layouts. [image -link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q4jBB.png)

Comment: did you try to have a relative layout container, and make the semi-transparent view alignparentleft?

Comment: yes, I tried to have a relative layout for container, but if I do it - i can't keep the equal height of the other elements.

Comment: how is your layout? could you post them all? and how is the effect look, could you post a picture?

Comment: This is picture of my xml file - [xml file pic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oSAqv.png)  - you can check the other pictures how exactly look like on the device

Comment: why do you have four some linear layout? what do you mean by " i can't keep the equal height of the other elements."?

Comment: because I have 4 rows and every row contains one text view and one chart. I want these rows to be equal and to fill the whole screen. Ff course every row is with different text and chart.

Comment: what do you mean by " i can't keep the equal height of the other elements."?

Comment: LinearLayout has " android:layout_weight="1" " - if this property is with same value of elements(layout or other) the height will be the same for all. For example i have  4 horizontal linear layouts - when I put  android:layout_weight="1" to all of them - they will be equal. And if I use Relative Layout for container - I can't use this property - because is missing for this layout.

Comment: when you post here http://i.stack.imgur.com/fkHvG.png , what is in the left? is it the column you want to turn up when user clicked?

Comment: In the left is text view, on right - chart. It is same as in the xml file. [Picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ziaea.png) The picture you posted is the layout as is now. When i click somewhere on the screen - the transparent column/overlay should be shown on this place. The problem is how to add this column (view) over the other layout ?

Comment: so what is the " click somewhere on the screen to add a highlighted column from top to bottom"?

Comment: check my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. It's not exactly what I tried to achieve, but you gave some direction and I did it as I want.

The solutions was to add Relative Layout as root and keep everything as-is, to keep the design.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j18Dw.png

I was doing wrong when I tried to replace my Linear layout container with Relative layout - I just needed to add all my things in new Relative container (not to replace).

Thanks.